# Problem with embedded SVG height in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, svg, embed

I have a large SVG file (1100x44000 px) embedded in my html webpage. My code works like a charm on Firefox 4, but does not display properly on IE8 w/ Adobe plugin.

More precisely, when I embed my SVG in a EMBED (or IFRAME) tag, for all values of attribute *height* <= 16382 px it works just well, but above this value the content is not displayed at all !

I know IE8 has compatibility issues with SVG. I tried the "compatibility view" on IE and tried also to add  but that doesnt help.

Any help appreciated :)

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
<table style="width:1100px;">
 <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
    <div class="title" >data</div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <div id="DivCont"   class="SVG_container">  
      <embed src="./NC_012587/out.svg" style="margin-top:30px; overflow:hidden;"  width="1100" height="44000" />
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Some CSS:

```
tr{
    width:1100px;
}

td{
border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

td.box{  
  background-color: #f5eded; 
  margin-top: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 200px;
}

div.SVG_container{
 height:600px;
 width:1100px;
     overflow:scroll;
 position:relative; 
}

rect.select_div{
position: absolute;
height: 30px;
width: 98px;
background: #CCF;
border: 1px solid #AAD;
text-align: center;
font-size: 10px;
border:1px solid black;
  /* for IE */
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
 /* CSS3 standard */
opacity:0.6;    
}
```

Comment: Since you already know that IE8 does not support SVG at all (I already told you in a previous question), you should specify what product you're using to add SVG support. The problem will likely be with that product, not with IE8.

Comment: How does it work with Chrome? Instead to using the Adobe Plugin, maybe you could recommend that people use Google Chrome Frame instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `<object>` tag instead of `<embed>`. For me the object tag is working in IE8. It may have some issues but basically it displays the SVG.